# can't load cross compiler header files into main.c

Tags: c, cmake, clion, avr-gcc, toolchain

trying to compile this AVR microprocessor source file Clion can't manage to load include files into the project
**CMakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(avr C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(avr main.c)
```

**main.c**

```
#include <avr/io.h> // stretch red line because clion can't find it

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

also I used

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=config.cmake
```

config.cmake

```
SET(MCU "atmega328")
SET(F_CPU "16000000")
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)

# For some reason, these paths have to be absolute, otherwise
# CLion won't be able to find headers etc.
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/homebrew/Cellar/avr-gcc@11/11.3.0_1/bin/avr-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/homebrew/Cellar/avr-gcc@11/11.3.0_1/bin/avr-g++)

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-mmcu=${MCU} -DF_CPU=${F_CPU} -Os")
SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS "-mmcu=${MCU}")

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
# set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

now my question is where do I need to change to make the clion find the avr-gcc library files? appreciate any help in advance
also I need to say that the header files that I seek to add to my source is in Clion Header Search Paths

Comment: Possibly one of the following: [`CMAKE_SYSROOT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html), or [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html)? I'd wager the former, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @user and would it need to be added to config.cmake or elsewhere?

Comment: your toolchain file is a good place to put it since it's related to the toolchain (the compiler installation). Again, I'm not 100% sure that's actually the variable you're looking for.

Comment: @user set(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILE_OPTIONS_SYSROOT "--sysroot=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/avr-gcc@11/11.3.0_1/avr") this didn't do it

Comment: `set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/avr-gcc@11/11.3.0_1/avr")`?

Comment: @user unfortunately no help in it