# Cmake include directories doesn't find the header files when cross compiling

Tags: c, cmake, avr

having to compile AVR source file can't manage to find the right toolchain Cmake file to find the headers in my main.c file any help would be appreciated

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(avr C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(avr main.c)
```

**config.cmake**

```
SET(MCU "atmega328")
SET(F_CPU "16000000")
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)

# For some reason, these paths have to be absolute, otherwise
# CLion won't be able to find headers etc.
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/homebrew/Cellar/avr-gcc@11/11.3.0_1/bin/avr-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/homebrew/Cellar/avr-gcc@11/11.3.0_1/bin/avr-g++)

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-mmcu=${MCU} -DF_CPU=${F_CPU} -Os")
SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS "-mmcu=${MCU}")

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /opt/homebrew/opt/avr-gcc@11/avr)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
#SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH "${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}/include")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH "${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}/lib")

include_directories(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH})
include_directories("/Users/clonerplus/desktop/avr")
```

I used Clion to configure the project and used

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=config.cmake
```

**main.c**

```
#include <avr/io.h> // stretch red line because clion can't find it

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

**build**

```
====================[ Build | avr | Debug ]=====================================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/clonerplus/desktop/avr/cmake-build-debug --target avr -j 6
[1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/avr.dir/main.c.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/avr.dir/main.c.o 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc   -g -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -std=gnu99 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/avr.dir/main.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/avr.dir/main.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/avr.dir/main.c.o -c /Users/clonerplus/desktop/avr/main.c
/Users/clonerplus/desktop/avr/main.c:2:10: fatal error: 'avr/io.h' file not found
#include <avr/io.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Have you updated the `config.cmake` file after you ran `cmake` and configured the project? IIRC it used to be that cross-compilation settings could not be changed or updated once the project was created. You needed to delete all CMake-generated files and rerun with a clean slate.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste all commands you use to configure and build your project and the output/errors you get. (You can shorten the output to the important parts if it's very long.)

Comment: Does this question is about the same problem as [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75637721/cant-load-cross-compiler-header-files-into-main-c)? If yes, then there is no need to ask the question again.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in the sense of Clion which files has to be deleted and regenerated?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes but no answer was given thought to ask the question in another way

Comment: Basically the whole `cmake-build-debug` directory (or what it might be called in your configuration).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude deleted all  ```cmake-build-debug``` files and ran Cmake successfully but the error is not yet gone or changed

Comment: Where *exactly* is the `avr/io.h` header file located? What is the full and absolute path to that header file?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks it worked but not on the same project had to make a new one and now it finds the header files can't manage to find the .hex file now :/

Comment: I meant that you needed to tell *us* the full path to the header file, not that you should include it using the full path. If the file is (for example) `/opt/homebrew/opt/avr-gcc@11/avr/io.h` then you need to either include `<io.h>` or change the path in your CMake file to `/opt/homebrew/opt/avr-gcc@11`. Otherwise the compiler would look for `/opt/homebrew/opt/avr-gcc@11/avr/avr/io.h`.

Comment: The output shows the `cmake --build` command but not the `cmake` command that was used to configure the project. Edit the `CMakeLists.txt` or remove the build directory to force a reconfiguration.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to set [`CMAKE_SYSROOT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) in your toolchain file?